# Solve differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, functions

I want to solve the next differential equation,

```
fun = t^2*x''[t] + 4/3*t*x'[t] - 2/3*(1 - (L^2)/(6*t^(2/3))) x[t] - (2*L^2)/(45*t^(2/3)) == 0

DSolve[fun, x, t]
```

The solutions are given in term of Bessel function. I do not know how to solve it. Any suggestion?
The problem is the next
[image]
but I don't get to do.

Comment: Your code works for me although it takes awhile.  What answer are you looking for?

Comment: I need that solution to be in Bessel function, that I do not obtain. Thank's

Comment: I've had a little look, and by adding assumptions `t>0` and `L>0` and using `FullSimplify` I can get a version in terms of `Sin` and `Cos`.  I believe that half-integer Bessel functions can be expressed in terms of trigonometric functions.  You may have more luck if you supply some boundary conditions.

Comment: If you evaluate `BesselJ[5/2, L/t^(1/3)]`, MMA returns the result in terms of sin and cos.  Having it reverse simplify back to Bessel functions might be tough.  Also, I can't get your solution to satisfy your `fun`.  Is there something missing?

Comment: The suggestion of @mikado helped to simplify the compilation time, but still does not give the solution that I am looking for and I put the real problem where it does not have initial conditions since it can be seen that it depends on constants C1 and C2.

Comment: If you want Mathematica to prove that `expr1` is equivalent to `expr2`, you can apply `FullSimplify` to `expr1==expr2`.  For this to work, you would obviously need to find equivalent values for the integration constants `C_1` and `C_2`